# Rewrite rules to handle both mediawiki and wordpress installation in same domain

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mediawiki

I have installed both wordpress and mediawiki in the single domain like this,

- `(domain root)/wp`  (wordpress installation directory)
- `(domain root)/wiki` (mediawiki installation directory)

The use case i like to achieve is,

- `www.domain.com`   -> This should load `www.domain.com/wp/index.php`
- `www.domain.com/wiki/` -> This has to load `www.domain.com/wiki/index.php`

I use a shared web host and need to use only `.htaccess` to achieve above use case.

What i have currently,

/.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domain.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wp/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /wp/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domain.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ wp/index.php [L] 
</IfModule>
```

/wp/.htaccess

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wp
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

/wiki/.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?wiki/page(/.*)?$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/wiki/index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?wiki/images/thumb/[0-9a-f]/[0-9a-f][0-9a-f]/([^/]+)/([0-9]+)px-.*$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/wiki/thumb.php?f=$1&width=$2 [L,QSA,B]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?wiki/images/thumb/archive/[0-9a-f]/[0-9a-f][0-9a-f]/([^/]+)/([0-9]+)px-.*$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/wiki/thumb.php?f=$1&width=$2&archived=1 [L,QSA,B]
```

Currently all the wordpress pages works normally. But when i access `www.domain.com/wiki` server gives "Not Found" error page.

I am new to all these rewrite rules. I guess the `.htaccess` at the root must be modified. But i don't know how to do it.